# How to establish a connection to a web server with NSURL in which variables can be passed securely via URL to PHP script

Tags: php, swift, security, url

I am using Swift's NSURL function to connect to a PHP script that I can use to interact with a MySQL database. Everything is running smoothly except for the insecurity of the variables passed in the URL via POST. If someone were to intercept these variables it would pose an enormous security risk to my application. I have researched the subject extensively however I have hit a wall. Is an SSL certificate enough to secure the URL? I am not passing the variables through the literal URL but a POST method. As far as I know, the SSL certificate provides security for the data passed AFTER the initial connection (meaning that the data originally passed via POST and the URL are not secure). So essentially, how do I go about passing variables to a web server securely?
Here is the code I am using to establish the connection:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://testsite.com/login.php”)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = “username=bob&password=123"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                        if let responseData = data {
                        let responseString = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


                        }
                    }
         } else {
             self.sendAlert("Error", message: "Unable to establish connection")
         }
}
```

Comment: you could pass the variable in the header instead of the body, and use encryption for your values
`request.addValue("bob", forHTTPHeaderField: "username")`
        `request.addValue("123", forHTTPHeaderField: "password") // add AES Encryption`. Also, you can implement a token system instead of passing your username and password. You would however have to pass it initially to get the token.

Comment: @AmornNarula Thank you for the help. I will definitely use the header method. As for the encryption, I have found it very difficult to find information on using encryption in Swift. All I have found is Cryptoswift which seems to be very difficult to use and I've read is insecure. Can you recommend another way to use AES encryption for the password? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [raywenderlich tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift) for setting up the iOS part of it. This tutorial is for connection between ruby rails and swift. It has sign in, sign up and token system, it also includes encryption.

The tutorial uses httpBody to pass the information, you can stick with that or modify to header instead to personalise your codes as required.

```
request.addValue("bob", forHTTPHeaderField: "username")
request.addValue("123", forHTTPHeaderField: "password") // add AES Encryption.
```

Also, you can implement a token system instead of passing your username and password. You would however have to pass it initially to get the token.